# How to handle TCP messages winch are segmented

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, bytestream

### CONTEXT

I'm trying to implement an Android application that use the SoulSeek protocol. The protocol is poorly documented so I have to try and analyses the streams.

If you are curious, the link to the documented protocol : https://www.museek-plus.org/wiki/SoulseekProtocol

---

### PROBLEM

When the TCP segment are complete, there are no problems cause the length of the message are sent. But when the messages are segmented I have to wait for the next message to concatenate the bytes and read the message.
There is a proper way to handle that segmented messages ?

I have tried to implement a function that use a rest when the socket is readed and concatenate with the next message this rest. But the problem is when the socket is readed, often the int returned is my length of my bytes array.

---

### SNIPPET

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    mRun = true;
    try {
        Log.d("SOCKET", "C: Connecting...");
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(mHost, mPort), 2000);
        sendMessage(login("Airmess", "159753"));
        setDefaultPort(2242);
        try {
            mOutputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            mInputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            byte[] data;
            int sizeData;
            while (mRun) {
                data = new byte[65536];
                int count;
                count = mInputStream.read(data, 0, data.length);
                Log.d("StackOverflowLog", "count: " + count);
                Log.d("StackOverflowLog", "messageBytes: " + Arrays.toString(data));
                Log.d("bytesMessageServer", Arrays.toString(data));
                if (count > 0) {
                    if (count < 4) {
                        rest = Arrays.copyOf(data, count);
                    } else {
                        if (rest != null && rest.length != 0) {
                            data = concatBytesArrays(rest, Arrays.copyOf(data, count));
                            if (data.length < 4) {
                                rest = data;
                            } else {
                                data = Arrays.copyOf(data, count);
                                sizeData = readIntLe(data, 0) + 4;
                                if (sizeData <= data.length) {
                                    rest = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, sizeData, count);
                                    mServerMessageListener.serverMessageReceived(data);
                                } else {
                                    rest = data;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            sizeData = readIntLe(data, 0) + 4;
                            if (sizeData <= count) {
                                rest = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, sizeData, count);
                                mServerMessageListener.serverMessageReceived(data);
                            } else {
                                rest = data;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (rest != null && rest.length > 0) {
                        sizeData = readIntLe(rest, 0) + 4;
                        if (sizeData <= rest.length) {
                            data = Arrays.copyOfRange(rest, 0, sizeData);
                            rest = Arrays.copyOfRange(rest, sizeData, rest.length);
                            mServerMessageListener.serverMessageReceived(data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
        } finally {
            socket.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
    }
}
```

### LOGS

```
10-24 14:30:09.857 10979-10999/? D/SOCKET: C: Connecting...
10-24 14:30:10.171 10979-10999/? D/StackOverflowLog: count: 2654
10-24 14:30:10.178 10979-10999/? D/StackOverflowLog: messageBytes: [50, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -92, 28, -91, 37, 32, 0, 0, 0, 53, 53, 56, 51, 52, 49, 51, 52, 52, 51, 49, 54, 52, 98, 53, 54, 53, 48, 48, 100, 101, 102, 57, 97, 53, 51, 51, 99, 55, 99, 55, 48, 0, 32, 13, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, -85, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 33, 32, 33, 32, 83, 108, 115, 107, 32, 73, 100, 105, 111, 116, 115, 32, 33, 32, 33, 13, 0, 0, 0, 33, 32, 73, 116, 97, 108, 111, 32, 68, 105, 115, 99, 111, 24, 0, 0, 0, 33, 33, 33, 32, 57, 48, 39, 115, 32, 82, 97, 114, 101, 32, 82, 105, 100, 100, 105, 109, 32, 33, 33, 33, 10, 0, 0, 0, 33, 33, 82, 73, 68, 68, 73, 77, 33, 33, 13, 0, 0, 0, 33, 82, 101, 71, 71, 97, 101, 71, 97, 76, 97, 88, 121, 11, 0, 0, 0, 35, 72, 111, 114, 114, 111, 114, 99, 111, 114, 101, 10, 0, 0, 0, 35, 76, 97, 32, 70, 114, 97, 110, 99, 101, 14, 0, 0, 0, 35, 76, 97, 32, 70, 114, 97, 110, 99, 101, 32, 50, 46, 48, 14, 0, 0, 0, 35, 76, 97, 32, 70, 114, 97, 110, 99, 101, 32, 50, 46, 50, 19, 0, 0, 0, 35, 105, 99, 105, 108, 111, 109, 98, 114, 101, 45, 104, 97, 114, 100, 99, 111, 114, 101, 7, 0, 0, 0, 35, 112, 111, 108, 115, 107, 97, 7, 0, 0, 0, 35, 116, 101, 113, 110, 105, 120, 10, 0, 0, 0, 40, 65, 41, 32, 47, 47, 32, 40, 69, 41, 10, 0, 0, 0, 42, 42, 82, 73, 68, 68, 73, 77, 42, 42, 12, 0, 0, 0, 43, 66, 108, 97, 99, 107, 77, 101, 116, 97, 108, 43, 24, 0, 0, 0, 43, 72, 73, 80, 95, 72, 79, 80, 95, 83, 67, 69, 78, 69, 95, 82, 69, 76, 69, 65, 83, 69, 83, 43, 5, 0, 0, 0, 45, 81, 38, 65, 45, 4, 0, 0, 0, 47, 109, 117, 47, 23, 0, 0, 0, 49, 57, 53, 48, 32, 116, 111, 32, 49, 57, 55, 53, 32, 97, 107, 97, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 54, 48, 24, 0, 0, 0, 55, 48, 32, 82, 97, 114, 101, 32, 103, 114, 111, 111, 118, 101, 32, 83, 111, 117, 108, 32, 74, 97, 122, 122, 21, 0, 0, 0, 56, 48, 39, 115, 32, 49, 50, 32, 73, 110, 99, 104, 101, 115, 32, 38, 32, 77, 111, 114, 101, 8, 0, 0, 0, 57, 48, 39, 115, 32, 101, 109, 111, 3, 0, 0, 0, 58, 45, 41, 22, 0, 0, 0, 60, 62, 69, 108, 101, 99, 116, 114, 111, 110, 105, 99, 115, 32, 76, 97, 98, 101, 108, 115, 60, 62, 2, 0, 0, 0, 65, 43, 4, 0, 0, 0, 65, 67, 73, 68, 4, 0, 0, 0, 65, 67, 108, 68, 9, 0, 0, 0, 65, 82, 71, 69, 78, 84, 73, 78, 65, 9, 0, 0, 0, 65, 85, 83, 84, 82, 65, 76, 73, 65, 7, 0, 0, 0, 65, 108, 99, 111, 104, 111, 108, 7, 0, 0, 0, 65, 109, 98, 105, 101, 110, 116, 5, 0, 0, 0, 65, 110, 105, 109, 101, 10, 0, 0, 0, 65, 117, 100, 105, 111, 98, 111, 111, 107, 115, 10, 0, 0, 0, 65, 118, 97, 110, 116, 103, 97, 114, 100, 101, 18, 0, 0, 0, 66, 76, 85, 69, 83, 32, 66, 85, 78, 75, 69, 82, 32, 77, 85, 83, 73, 67, 14, 0, 0, 0, 66, 79, 66, 32, 68, 89, 76, 65, 78, 32, 82, 79, 79, 77, 16, 0, 0, 0, 66, 82, 85, 84, 65, 76, 68, 69, 65, 84, 72, 77, 69, 84, 65, 76, 10, 0, 0, 0, 66, 108, 117, 101, 115, 38, 83, 111, 117, 108, 6, 0, 0, 0, 66, 114, 97, 115, 105, 108, 9, 0, 0, 0, 66, 114, 101, 97, 107, 99, 111, 114, 101, 5, 0, 0, 0, 67, 72, 73, 76, 69, 6, 0, 0, 0, 67, 97, 110, 97, 100, 97, 10, 0, 0, 0, 67, 104, 105, 110, 97, 32, 82, 111, 111, 109, 9, 0, 0, 0, 67, 104, 105, 112, 116, 117, 110, 101, 115, 9, 0, 0, 0, 67, 108, 97, 115, 115, 105, 99, 97, 108, 9, 0, 0, 0, 67, 111, 109, 109, 117, 110, 105, 115, 109, 16, 0, 0, 0, 68, 69, 65, 84, 72, 32, 77, 69, 84, 65, 76, 32, 67, 76, 85, 66, 3, 0, 0, 0, 68, 85, 66, 12, 0, 0, 0, 68, 97, 114, 107, 32, 65, 109, 98, 105, 101, 110, 116, 14, 0, 0, 0, 68, 101, 32, 75, 111, 102, 102, 105, 101, 32, 83, 104, 111, 112, 8, 0, 0, 0, 68, 101, 32, 75, 114, 111, 101, 103, 9, 0, 0, 0, 68, 101, 97, 116, 104, 114, 111, 99, 107, 15, 0, 0, 0, 68, 105, 101, 77, 105, 108, 105, 116, 97, 114, 109, 117, 115, 105, 107, 10, 0, 0, 0, 68, 111, 111, 109, 32, 77, 101, 116, 97, 108, 10, 0, 0, 0, 68, 117, 98, 32, 84, 101, 99, 104, 110, 111, 7, 0, 0, 0, 68, 117, 98, 115, 116, 101, 112, 21, 0, 0, 0, 69, 66, 77, 45, 71, 79, 84, 72, 73, 67, 45, 73, 78, 68, 85, 83, 84, 82, 73, 65, 76, 6, 0, 0, 0, 69, 66, 111, 111, 107, 115, 9, 0, 0, 0, 69, 117, 114, 111, 100, 97, 110, 99, 101, 23, 0, 0, 0, 69, 117, 114, 111, 118, 105, 115, 105, 111, 110, 32, 83, 111, 110, 103, 32, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 115, 116, 24, 0, 0, 0, 69, 120, 112, 101, 114, 105, 109, 101, 110, 
10-24 14:30:10.194 10979-10999/? D/StackOverflowLog: count: 9100
10-24 14:30:10.209 10979-10999/? D/StackOverflowLog: messageBytes: [69, 97, 100, 100, 105, 99, 116, 7, 0, 0, 0, 119, 104, 97, 116, 46, 99, 100, 18, 0, 0, 0, 119, 104, 97, 116, 46, 99, 100, 32, 101, 108, 101, 99, 116, 114, 111, 110, 105, 99, 12, 0, 0, 0, 119, 104, 97, 116, 46, 99, 100, 45, 102, 108, 97, 99, -85, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 111, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 111, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 44, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 72, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 46, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 34, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 38, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 38, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 35, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 71, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 92, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 52, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 79, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, -113, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 34, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, -124, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 83, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 84, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 104, 0, 0, 0, -48, 2, 0, 0, 11, 69, 0, 0, 69, 0, 0, 0, 66, 5, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 100, 101, 118, 97, 110, 116, 10, 0, 0, 0, 97, 112, 114, 105, 108, 56, 49, 57, 55, 50, 12, 0, 0, 0, 103, 114, 97, 104, 97, 109, 98, 97, 115, 116, 101, 114, 7, 0, 0, 0, 80, 101, 116, 101, 114, 85, 75, 7, 0, 0, 0, 100, 106, 106, 117, 114, 110, 105, 7, 0, 0, 0, 80, 82, 83, 85, 65, 68, 65, 10, 0, 0, 0, 71, 114, 101, 101, 110, 98, 97, 117, 110, 95, 11, 0, 0, 0, 99, 111, 114, 110, 105, 108, 105, 107, 101, 105, 116, 4, 0, 0, 0, 107, 116, 122, 97, 10, 0, 0, 0, 117, 115, 101, 114, 53, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 14, 0, 0, 0, 70, 114, 101, 101, 115, 116, 121, 108, 101, 74, 111, 107, 101, 114, 3, 0, 0, 0, 97, 114, 103, 4, 0, 0, 0, 99, 97, 109, 98, 14, 0, 0, 0, 79, 104, 95, 83, 121, 110, 116, 104, 101, 115, 105, 122, 101, 114, 10, 0, 0, 0, 108, 105, 101, 102, 104, 101, 98, 98, 101, 114, 3, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 102, 4, 0, 0, 0, 68, 74, 76, 88, 19, 0, 0, 0, 99, 97, 109, 101, 119, 105, 116, 104, 111, 117, 116, 97, 119, 97, 114, 110, 105, 110, 103, 8, 0, 0, 0, 109, 115, 116, 114, 101, 118, 101, 114, 12, 0, 0, 0, 90, 111, 109, 98, 105, 101, 82, 111, 98, 98, 49, 51, 6, 0, 0, 0, 71, 45, 83, 116, 97, 114, 16, 0, 0, 0, 97, 114, 97, 110, 99, 105, 97, 95, 109, 101, 99, 97, 110, 105, 99, 97, 8, 0, 0, 0, 100, 97, 118, 101, 116, 117, 98, 97, 7, 0, 0, 0, 115, 110, 97, 103, 103, 101, 108, 7, 0, 0, 0, 99, 111, 114, 101, 121, 107, 49, 7, 0, 0, 0, 115, 104, 105, 101, 107, 105, 101, 6, 0, 0, 0, 97, 1
10-24 14:30:10.304 10979-10999/? D/StackOverflowLog: count: 3900
10-24 14:30:10.309 10979-10999/? D/StackOverflowLog: messageBytes: [102, 115, 64, 108, 105, 118, 101, 46, 99, 111, 109, 10, 0, 0, 0, 101, 97, 122, 121, 112, 101, 101, 108, 101, 114, 13, 0, 0, 0, 100, 114, 97, 105, 110, 101, 100, 99, 111, 108, 111, 114, 115, 7, 0, 0, 0, 106, 108, 109, 51, 51, 51, 51, 6, 0, 0, 0, 99, 114, 105, 115, 97, 110, 6, 0, 0, 0, 115, 106, 116, 108, 113, 121, 6, 0, 0, 0, 70, 97, 116, 98, 97, 116, 9, 0, 0, 0, 72, 97, 109, 109, 111, 99, 108, 101, 115, 8, 0, 0, 0, 97, 110, 100, 121, 119, 101, 108, 116, 9, 0, 0, 0, 114, 119, 120, 114, 45, 120, 114, 45, 120, 10, 0, 0, 0, 103, 97, 108, 108, 105, 119, 97, 115, 112, 50, 8, 0, 0, 0, 86, 105, 110, 116, 122, 110, 99, 111, 9, 0, 0, 0, 84, 74, 45, 84, 104, 101, 109, 101, 115, 17, 0, 0, 0, 105, 102, 46, 116, 104, 101, 110, 46, 111, 116, 104, 101, 114, 119, 105, 115, 101, 6, 0, 0, 0, 97, 110, 100, 119, 101, 114, 11, 0, 0, 0, 83, 113, 117, 105, 100, 76, 105, 113, 117, 105, 100, 7, 0, 0, 0, 100, 117, 107, 101, 118, 105, 110, 11, 0, 0, 0, 110, 105, 103, 104, 116, 103, 111, 97, 116, 55, 52, 12, 0, 0, 0, 84, 111, 112, 79, 98, 101, 110, 66, 111, 118, 101, 110, 7, 0, 0, 0, 111, 112, 117, 110, 116, 105, 97, 13, 0, 0, 0, 112, 105, 101, 97, 110, 100, 97, 98, 108, 111, 119, 105, 101, 5, 0, 0, 0, 114, 101, 101, 115, 121, 12, 0, 0, 0, 72, 101, 110, 116, 97, 105, 109, 97, 115, 116, 101, 114, 6, 0, 0, 0, 98, 108, 97, 122, 97, 114, 7, 0, 0, 0, 65, 65, 114, 116, 97, 117, 100, 11, 0, 0, 0, 66, 97, 98, 121, 108, 111, 110, 83, 111, 117, 108, 8, 0, 0, 0, 108, 117, 99, 97, 115, 115, 115, 111, 11, 0, 0, 0, 112, 111, 112, 111, 112, 111, 112, 111, 112, 111, 112, 18, 0, 0, 0, 114, 101, 103, 116, 111, 110, 101, 64, 114, 111, 103, 101, 114, 115, 46, 99, 111, 109, 8, 0, 0, 0, 83, 107, 97, 116, 101, 101, 57, 57, 8, 0, 0, 0, 112, 104, 111, 110, 111, 109, 105, 114, 13, 0, 0, 0, 87, 101, 120, 102, 111, 114, 100, 82, 97, 105, 100, 101, 114, 10, 0, 0, 0, 77, 101, 116, 104, 117, 115, 97, 108, 97, 104, 7, 0, 0, 0, 100, 111, 109, 109, 101, 100, 106, 9, 0, 0, 0, 115, 97, 110, 100, 105, 97, 98, 108, 111, 4, 0, 0, 0, 104, 101, 102, 97, 5, 0, 0, 0, 116, 117, 97, 110, 97, 5, 0, 0, 0, 109, 101, 107, 97, 115, 10, 0, 0, 0, 121, 101, 108, 108, 111, 119, 98, 101, 108, 116, 4, 0, 0, 0, 115, 108, 101, 100, 3, 0, 0, 0, 78, 47, 65, 6, 0, 0, 0, 67, 104, 105, 108, 97, 109, 7, 0, 0, 0, 114, 116, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 7, 0, 0, 0, 107, 101, 118, 115, 116, 101, 103, 6, 0, 0, 0, 116, 97, 113, 54, 54, 54, 9, 0, 0, 0, 106, 97, 100, 122, 101, 105, 108, 97, 104, 9, 0, 0, 0, 107, 117, 116, 97, 114, 97, 116, 117, 107, 11, 0, 0, 0, 72, 101, 114, 98, 95, 68, 97, 119, 111, 111, 100, 12, 0, 0, 0, 100, 105, 115, 105, 122, 108, 97, 112, 101, 115, 116, 101, 11, 0, 0, 0, 64, 115, 112, 101, 97, 107, 101, 97, 115, 121, 64, 11, 0, 0, 0, 100, 105, 103, 105, 116, 97, 108, 115, 111, 117, 108, 8, 0, 0, 0, 109, 111, 110, 116, 121, 99, 97, 116, 11, 0, 0, 0, 109, 97, 120, 120, 98, 97, 115, 115, 50, 50, 50, 9, 0, 0, 0, 76, 111, 117, 100, 109, 117, 115, 105, 99, 11, 0, 0, 0, 83, 111, 117, 108, 32, 83, 105, 115, 116, 101, 114, 9, 0, 0, 0, 103, 114, 111, 111, 118, 101, 115, 95, 49, 8, 0, 0, 0, 97, 95, 99, 97, 116, 97, 108, 97, 10, 0, 0, 0, 116, 104, 101, 100, 106, 107, 121, 108, 101, 106, 10, 0, 0, 0, 106, 108, 97, 110, 103, 101, 49, 55, 48, 55, 5, 0, 0, 0, 107, 97, 114, 111, 110, 7, 0, 0, 0, 50, 110, 100, 108, 105, 110, 101, 4, 0, 0, 0, 76, 117, 112, 97, 11, 0, 0, 0, 68, 105, 118, 105, 110, 101, 32, 87, 105, 110, 100, 8, 0, 0, 0, 98, 105, 108, 108, 120, 117, 48, 57, 11, 0, 0, 0, 84, 111, 109, 109, 121, 107, 98, 51, 103, 114, 122, 13, 0, 0, 0, 73, 116, 111, 114, 121, 95, 86, 105, 108, 108, 97, 103, 101, 8, 0, 0, 0, 77, 97, 114, 116, 118, 108, 97, 116, 5, 0, 0, 0, 114, 101, 109, 100, 51, 8, 0, 0, 0, 112, 115, 97, 108, 109, 105, 115, 116, 10, 0, 0, 0, 101, 112, 115, 111, 110, 115, 97, 108, 116, 115, 10, 0, 0, 0, 76, 111, 114, 100, 32, 78, 111, 105, 114, 101, 12, 0, 0, 0, 97, 110, 116, 111, 110, 46, 115, 116, 121, 108, 101, 115, 26, 0, 0, 0, 103, 97, 108, 105, 97, 110, 111, 116, 105, 116, 111, 111, 50, 51, 64, 104, 111, 116, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 9,
10-24 14:30:10.315 10979-10999/? D/StackOverflowLog: count: 1300
10-24 14:30:10.321 10979-10999/? D/StackOverflowLog: messageBytes: [101, 99, 101, 108, 108, 97, 10, 0, 0, 0, 99, 104, 111, 99, 111, 99, 104, 111, 99, 111, 8, 0, 0, 0, 100, 101, 98, 101, 99, 116, 111, 114, 13, 0, 0, 0, 83, 116, 97, 114, 115, 79, 118, 84, 104, 101, 76, 105, 100, 7, 0, 0, 0, 69, 108, 110, 105, 108, 105, 111, 5, 0, 0, 0, 120, 121, 114, 105, 120, 9, 0, 0, 0, 98, 97, 105, 115, 105, 109, 111, 110, 101, 14, 0, 0, 0, 109, 101, 110, 105, 110, 116, 104, 101, 99, 105, 116, 105, 101, 115, 7, 0, 0, 0, 97, 110, 116, 104, 111, 109, 112, 6, 0, 0, 0, 99, 98, 54, 55, 54, 57, 8, 0, 0, 0, 116, 111, 114, 118, 105, 108, 108, 101, 5, 0, 0, 0, 99, 105, 103, 101, 115, 9, 0, 0, 0, 100, 111, 111, 102, 121, 120, 112, 113, 116, 5, 0, 0, 0, 111, 83, 99, 97, 114, 10, 0, 0, 0, 116, 104, 105, 115, 115, 112, 101, 114, 115, 111, 9, 0, 0, 0, 110, 48, 48, 98, 109, 97, 114, 105, 111, 11, 0, 0, 0, 68, 74, 95, 70, 85, 84, 85, 82, 65, 77, 65, 16, 0, 0, 0, 108, 105, 102, 101, 115, 117, 110, 99, 101, 114, 116, 97, 105, 110, 116, 121, 6, 0, 0, 0, 83, 116, 69, 101, 90, 121, 12, 0, 0, 0, 100, 114, 111, 115, 111, 112, 104, 105, 108, 97, 55, 49, 10, 0, 0, 0, 100, 106, 108, 97, 117, 114, 101, 110, 122, 111, 21, 0, 0, 0, 105, 110, 103, 97, 105, 119, 97, 110, 111, 119, 97, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109, 6, 0, 0, 0, 109, 112, 115, 111, 117, 108, 10, 0, 0, 0, 122, 101, 110, 99, 104, 105, 99, 107, 101, 110, 7, 0, 0, 0, 68, 101, 110, 101, 98, 56, 49, 9, 0, 0, 0, 66, 97, 108, 32, 77, 111, 114, 97, 108, 11, 0, 0, 0, 74, 111, 111, 115, 121, 95, 74, 111, 111, 115, 101, 11, 0, 0, 0, 72, 111, 114, 115, 101, 115, 104, 105, 116, 55, 48, 7, 0, 0, 0, 110, 105, 110, 106, 97, 108, 111, 15, 0, 0, 0, 115, 104, 121, 110, 116, 115, 97, 110, 100, 99, 108, 105, 99, 107, 115, 6, 0, 0, 0, 100, 106, 111, 110, 121, 99, 6, 0, 0, 0, 114, 117, 103, 101, 114, 111, 11, 0, 0, 0, 99, 114, 121, 115, 116, 97, 108, 115, 104, 105, 116, 11, 0, 0, 0, 106, 97, 109, 101, 115, 98, 114, 105, 97, 110, 99, 12, 0, 0, 0, 99, 104, 97, 114, 108, 105, 101, 95, 103, 111, 108, 100, 13, 0, 0, 0, 106, 97, 114, 106, 97, 114, 116, 104, 101, 100, 117, 100, 101, 9, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 114, 101, 116, 114, 97, 100, 101, 5, 0, 0, 0, 84, 119, 101, 101, 107, 16, 0, 0, 0, 107, 101, 108, 118, 105, 110, 116, 104, 101, 109, 97, 114, 116, 105, 97, 110, 12, 0, 0, 0, 114, 105, 100, 99, 117, 108, 108, 121, 48, 49, 48, 49, 6, 0, 0, 0, 97, 119, 99, 50, 55, 57, 7, 0, 0, 0, 110, 117, 110, 111, 114, 117, 102, 7, 0, 0, 0, 115, 116, 101, 101, 108, 111, 49, 12, 0, 0, 0, 97, 103, 101, 110, 116, 115, 109, 105, 116, 104, 52, 52, 13, 0, 0, 0, 66, 101, 97, 116, 115, 116, 114, 101, 101, 116, 117, 107, 49, 10, 0, 0, 0, 104, 117, 109, 97, 110, 116, 114, 97, 115, 104, 7, 0, 0, 0, 84, 114, 97, 110, 99, 101, 116, 9, 0, 0, 0, 115, 112, 101, 99, 105, 97, 108, 50, 51, 7, 0, 0, 0, 115, 116, 111, 112, 112, 101, 100, 10, 0, 0, 0, 99, 97, 121, 100, 101, 110, 51, 49, 50, 49, 12, 0, 0, 0, 77, 105, 108, 108, 101, 110, 105, 117, 109, 109, 97, 110, 8, 0, 0, 0, 110, 111, 114, 97, 99, 97, 116, 50, 10, 0, 0, 0, 66, 117, 111, 110, 103, 105, 111, 114, 110, 111, 9, 0, 0, 0, 116, 101, 115, 115, 105, 101, 114, 100, 108, 7, 0, 0, 0, 101, 108, 105, 107, 97, 117, 102, 5, 0, 0, 0, 111, 117, 114, 111, 98, 6, 0, 0, 0, 75, 97, 105, 100, 101, 110, 7, 0, 0, 0, 100, 97, 104, 105, 99, 97, 110, 7, 0, 0, 0, 112, 97, 110, 116, 109, 97, 110, 15, 0, 0, 0, 67, 101, 115, 97, 114, 84, 97, 100, 97, 108, 97, 102, 105, 108, 97, 9, 0, 0, 0, 67, 111, 114, 118, 117, 115, 32, 67, 90, 10, 0, 0, 0, 116, 114, 105, 102, 111, 114, 99, 101, 39, 100, 11, 0, 0, 0, 112, 111, 112, 115, 116, 97, 114, 50, 48, 48, 48, 9, 0, 0, 0, 98, 108, 101, 115, 116, 112, 104, 111, 110, 9, 0, 0, 0, 106, 50, 109, 99, 114, 117, 115, 111, 101, 11, 0, 0, 0, 103, 97, 114, 105, 107, 112, 108, 101, 100, 111, 118, 6, 0, 0, 0, 74, 97, 66, 108, 117, 122, 8, 0, 0, 0, 102, 97, 105, 114, 99, 105, 116, 121, 10, 0, 0, 0, 108, 111, 117, 108, 97, 103, 97, 116, 116, 97, 7, 0, 0, 0, 103, 114, 101, 121, 102, 117, 115, 10, 0, 0, 0, 112, 97, 110, 110, 121, 116, 104, 105, 101, 102, 4, 0, 0, 0, 107, 101, 105, 114, 8, 0, 0, 0, 100, 106, 99,
10-24 14:30:10.325 10979-10999/? D/StackOverflowLog: count: 4179
10-24 14:30:10.329 10979-10999/? D/StackOverflowLog: messageBytes: [105, 108, 98, 111, 57, 8, 0, 0, 0, 80, 111, 108, 121, 114, 111, 99, 107, 6, 0, 0, 0, 74, 98, 111, 110, 105, 99, 8, 0, 0, 0, 100, 114, 121, 102, 105, 115, 116, 50, 6, 0, 0, 0, 109, 102, 104, 115, 97, 114, 9, 0, 0, 0, 118, 101, 108, 111, 99, 105, 102, 101, 114, 7, 0, 0, 0, 70, 100, 111, 103, 103, 101, 114, 11, 0, 0, 0, 122, 97, 109, 112, 97, 110, 111, 50, 48, 48, 52, 12, 0, 0, 0, 71, 111, 108, 100, 101, 110, 67, 114, 97, 116, 101, 115, 4, 0, 0, 0, 119, 108, 103, 49, 5, 0, 0, 0, 72, 75, 82, 48, 49, 8, 0, 0, 0, 78, 117, 109, 98, 101, 114, 53, 49, 10, 0, 0, 0, 115, 117, 112, 101, 114, 108, 111, 116, 101, 107, 6, 0, 0, 0, 108, 108, 101, 118, 48, 49, 11, 0, 0, 0, 66, 108, 117, 101, 115, 116, 98, 108, 111, 111, 100, 6, 0, 0, 0, 115, 121, 108, 101, 117, 115, 12, 0, 0, 0, 102, 114, 97, 110, 107, 95, 98, 108, 111, 116, 116, 111, 10, 0, 0, 0, 97, 114, 108, 117, 99, 97, 115, 105, 110, 99, 20, 0, 0, 0, 112, 114, 111, 102, 101, 115, 115, 101, 100, 95, 105, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 105, 111, 110, 115, 4, 0, 0, 0, 77, 73, 90, 73, 11, 0, 0, 0, 87, 79, 87, 72, 73, 71, 72, 71, 85, 89, 90, 15, 0, 0, 0, 98, 105, 116, 99, 104, 102, 114, 111, 109, 113, 117, 101, 101, 110, 115, 7, 0, 0, 0, 109, 101, 105, 109, 101, 110, 122, 9, 0, 0, 0, 67, 97, 110, 116, 111, 110, 55, 49, 49, 7, 0, 0, 0, 109, 97, 116, 116, 120, 53, 55, 7, 0, 0, 0, 105, 99, 111, 110, 57, 51, 50, 6, 0, 0, 0, 103, 52, 122, 122, 51, 114, 10, 0, 0, 0, 71, 114, 101, 110, 100, 101, 108, 54, 54, 54, 8, 0, 0, 0, 105, 109, 119, 105, 110, 110, 105, 110, 8, 0, 0, 0, 109, 101, 97, 110, 100, 97, 118, 101, 11, 0, 0, 0, 109, 121, 115, 116, 105, 99, 119, 111, 114, 107, 115, 7, 0, 0, 0, 100, 105, 115, 107, 111, 110, 111, 12, 0, 0, 0, 97, 117, 115, 116, 105, 110, 108, 117, 99, 107, 121, 55, 8, 0, 0, 0, 97, 98, 101, 114, 103, 97, 114, 121, 10, 0, 0, 0, 102, 117, 122, 122, 121, 102, 117, 122, 122, 121, 14, 0, 0, 0, 68, 117, 107, 97, 68, 105, 101, 115, 101, 108, 49, 50, 48, 53, 7, 0, 0, 0, 106, 100, 98, 50, 54, 52, 99, 10, 0, 0, 0, 115, 104, 111, 101, 103, 97, 122, 101, 54, 51, 9, 0, 0, 0, 100, 101, 118, 105, 108, 106, 105, 106, 110, 7, 0, 0, 0, 109, 97, 110, 110, 105, 97, 107, 11, 0, 0, 0, 101, 120, 105, 116, 112, 108, 111, 116, 116, 101, 114, 8, 0, 0, 0, 114, 103, 97, 114, 99, 105, 97, 100, 5, 0, 0, 0, 99, 105, 110, 99, 111, 8, 0, 0, 0, 104, 105, 116, 106, 97, 103, 101, 114, 12, 0, 0, 0, 76, 105, 118, 114, 97, 32, 70, 101, 118, 114, 101, 115, 5, 0, 0, 0, 119, 104, 121, 49, 56, 10, 0, 0, 0, 91, 110, 105, 102, 108, 117, 114, 105, 108, 93, 10, 0, 0, 0, 97, 108, 116, 111, 110, 101, 110, 116, 114, 101, 8, 0, 0, 0, 105, 99, 101, 119, 97, 118, 101, 115, 14, 0, 0, 0, 102, 117, 110, 107, 121, 98, 117, 100, 100, 104, 97, 52, 50, 48, 15, 0, 0, 0, 106, 97, 99, 107, 115, 116, 114, 105, 100, 101, 114, 98, 114, 101, 119, 11, 0, 0, 0, 102, 117, 122, 122, 116, 111, 110, 101, 114, 98, 101, 13, 0, 0, 0, 70, 117, 108, 108, 80, 108, 97, 116, 101, 77, 101, 97, 108, 10, 0, 0, 0, 97, 108, 116, 99, 111, 117, 110, 116, 114, 121, 9, 0, 0, 0, 112, 97, 110, 110, 111, 110, 105, 99, 97, 6, 0, 0, 0, 97, 97, 112, 97, 101, 115, 8, 0, 0, 0, 110, 98, 111, 109, 98, 50, 50, 48, 11, 0, 0, 0, 104, 111, 117, 115, 101, 121, 116, 117, 110, 101, 115, 4, 0, 0, 0, 107, 104, 114, 111, 9, 0, 0, 0, 71, 97, 100, 103, 101, 116, 77, 97, 110, 10, 0, 0, 0, 112, 105, 110, 112, 111, 110, 107, 101, 116, 111, 6, 0, 0, 0, 65, 76, 105, 95, 77, 116, 9, 0, 0, 0, 119, 97, 115, 116, 111, 102, 102, 49, 49, 7, 0, 0, 0, 99, 111, 114, 100, 108, 116, 120, 14, 0, 0, 0, 80, 114, 97, 99, 116, 105, 99, 97, 108, 67, 104, 97, 111, 115, 8, 0, 0, 0, 119, 111, 106, 109, 117, 115, 105, 99, 10, 0, 0, 0, 73, 114, 109, 105, 110, 116, 114, 117, 100, 101, 7, 0, 0, 0, 119, 101, 98, 101, 116, 116, 115, 8, 0, 0, 0, 82, 97, 116, 80, 102, 105, 110, 107, 12, 0, 0, 0, 35, 72, 113, 71, 119, 51, 111, 89, 89, 49, 109, 113, 8, 0, 0, 0, 115, 101, 114, 103, 105, 115, 101, 114, 8, 0, 0, 0, 109, 98, 101, 114, 105, 115, 115, 111, 10, 0, 0, 0, 98, 105, 114, 100, 112, 101, 114, 115, 111, 110, 9, 0, 0, 0, 98, 114, 97, 110, 100, 118, 101, 103, 110,
10-24 14:30:41.789 10979-10999/com.example.slsk_android D/StackOverflowLog: count: 45
10-24 14:30:41.796 10979-10999/com.example.slsk_android D/StackOverflowLog: messageBytes: [41, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 107, 117, 98, 97, 110, 101, 107, 1, 0, 0, 0, 80, 20, -104, -55, 109, -53, -38, 0, 0, -37, 51, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -52, -38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

I expect that the int returned by the method read is 0 to read the message in the rest but when no message arrived it's my data array length winch is returned ...

---

### EDIT

I saw a little thing when i was in debugging mode. The fact is when the socket i empty and I am in debuggin mode the count value is the data length array, but it's not printed in the logs. I'm asking my self what can i do to empty this rest whinch is growing up at all loop steps.

---

PS: this is my first question on SO, I know it's not clean but i will do my best for improve, Thanks !

Comment: It is quite normal when using TCP that you have to concatenate the incoming bytes unting you have a complete message. So you have to know at forehand how long a mesage is. This is mostly done by the server sending an integer(four bytes) representing the amount of bytes in the message. Even if the sever sends 100000 bytes in one go the client will get them im pieces of 8000-32000 or whatever.

Comment: Hi @blackapps, effectively it's normal. this behaviour is almost ok, but when searching on Google for code example there is nothing about this "segmented TCP messages". The biggest problem is that when nothing is available in the socket, the read method from InputStream return my data array length instead of 0 for exemple and it's a part of my last condition for read the message waiting in the rest buffer

Comment: `The biggest problem is that when nothing is available in the socket, the read method from InputStream return my data array length` That is hard to believe. The code would hang if it tried to read and there was nothing as the read function would not return.

Comment: I will add some logs this afternoon but when nothing is available in the socket, "count" (winch is the int returned by InputStream.read) is exactly equal to the data length declaration (65536). So my last "else" is never verified.